# Aplicativo Android e servidor windows - salvar arquivo no servidor

Tags: python, android, microsoft-excel

Montei um programa de vendas e analise de vendas, executado no windows, para uso no pc/servidor, e os outros PCs/Notes já montei a rede por acesso VPN, e todos rodam e salvam o arquivo dentro do servidor. Esses são arquivos são dois arquivos de Excel que servem como banco de dados, de cadastro de clientes e faturamento.
Gostaria de saber, se é possível, ter esse tipo de acesso a modificar o arquivo excel no servidor, ao criar o mesmo programa porém para utilização no Android e se essa informação tenho que colocar no código (se for possível vou atrás de descobrir como).

```
#Parte do código que salva/atualiza o arquivo Excel:
while True:
    window, eventos, valores = sg.read_all_windows()
    book = openpyxl.load_workbook('faturamento.xlsx')
    dados = book['dados_gerais']
    book2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('cadastro.xlsx')
    dados2 = book2['dados_gerais']
    df = pd.read_excel('faturamento.xlsx')
    df2 = pd.read_excel('cadastro.xlsx', dtype=str)
    df3 = list(df2['cnpj_cpf'])
...
    elif window == janela3 and eventos == 'CONFIRMAR':
        dados.append([ordem_de_venda, data, nome, m3, valor_unt, fat_total, cod_cliente, cod, None, ven])
        book.save('faturamento.xlsx')
        sg.Popup('VENDA FINALIZADA', no_titlebar=True,background_color='#171717')
        janela1 = janela_cadastro()
        janela3.hide()

Obrigada
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Nesse caso você precisa de um backend para fazer isso. Existem diversas alternativas para isso. Como seu código é Python, um Django ou Flask resolveriam isso. O Django possui já autenticação e um baita controle de usuários integrado.

Algumas questões devem ser consideradas nesse backend (ou web service por assim dizer), como:

- Segurança entre o aplicativo android e esse web service. Mesmo estando dentro de uma VPN, eu colocaria alguma autenticação, como "basic authentication" por exemplo;
- Concorrência: como um arquivo excel (ainda mais xlsx pois possui compactação) está sendo editado por mais de uma fonte, você precisaria de algum tipo de trava para que não fosse editado por mais de uma fonte. Creio que um banco de dados seria o ideal, a primeira vista;
- Histórico: editando um Arquivo excel diretamente, não há uma fonte de histórico confiável indicando quem fez o que no aplicativo.

Para banco de dados eu creio que um MySQL ou até um SQLite resolveriam, que também possuem drivers nativos para Django;

Comment: Muito obrigada!
Comecei a aprender programação a pouco tempo, e precisei desenvolver rápido esse programa para um comercio simples de venda de 1 item apenas, que irá abrir em breve.
Vou pesquisar sobre o MySQL para melhorar o sistema e sobre o Django.
Agradeço a atenção